# ReportViewer 2010 control either prints part of a table on a separate page or prints an extra empty page

Tags: c#, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I just started using ReportViewer control VS2010 (web, local).
My report is very simple - 4 columns, all fit on a screen fine.
When I click "print" button, the report is printed on 2 pages ( 2 columns on one and 2 on another).
If I change the margins on a page, all 4 pages are printed on the same page but I still have 2nd empty page printed as well.
If report spans across multiple pages (2 for example), with margins changed I get first page, second page is empty, then third page fine and the fourth page is empty.

Any suggestion how to make the report printed without empty pages?
Thank you,
Jenny

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (which has been a painful one...), I found that if the report is printing an extra page it means that somewhere, your margins or page size of the subreports (if you're using any) are not equaling 8.5 X 11 (or whatever size paper you're using).  make sure that your your table (i'm assuming that's what you're using?) is in the bounds of a sheet of paper.  keep in mind you need take an inch of of each side (if you're using .5" margins [.5" for each side]) to keep the table on one page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried setting margins with no luck.  Couldn't spend more time on this at that time so I ended up only allowing users to export to excel and word (that didn't have this problem) and print from there.  I had to disable report's default export and print feature and add a drop down allowing user to select word or excel for export.  Still don't know why it was behaving this way - but the users said they only use excel anyway.  So this was a work around.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you! To put it simply, the lack of support for report viewer 2010 is a pain in the butt!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and m.webster's answer was spot on for me.

Check that the SIZE property of the reports BODY is within your REPORTs Pagesize and Margin properties.

In my case, I had set my report to A4 and the properties of the report (click in the grey area of the designed) showed: PageSize: 21cm, 29.7cm. I built my report but printing resulted in content spilling over to a second page.

When I turned on the RULER option, it was immediately obvious that my reports BODY (white content area) was wider that then PageSize of the Reports page size.

When I reduced the BODY's size->width property down to 21cm (after rearranging all my content to allow this resizing) I found there I was still getting the second page problem. A quick change to the reports margins down to 0 resolved this.

The final white space problem I had was an empty page appearing at the end of some of my reports. This was resolved by reducing the height of the reports BODY so that there was no blank space after my content. Because the initial report body appears in a nice portrait layout, I had assumed that it was just representing the final page which was not the case.

Its a bit of a late answer to the problem but I've added it to save someone else the wasted hour of head scratching when using this slightly unintuitive piece of kit.